# Get only part of an Object from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need help in defining only part of the `logo` `object` as `logoName` in my **JSON** Data

```
{  
   "2017-12-17":[  

   ],
   "2017-12-18":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":1,
         "nb_actions":5,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":5,
         "sum_visit_length":184,
         "bounce_count":0,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      }
   ],
   "2017-12-19":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":7,
         "nb_actions":29,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":15,
         "sum_visit_length":4195,
         "bounce_count":2,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      },
      {  
         "label":"Mobile Safari",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":2,
         "nb_visits":2,
         "nb_actions":2,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":1,
         "sum_visit_length":0,
         "bounce_count":2,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/MF.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==MF"
      }
   ],
   "2017-12-20":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":1,
         "nb_actions":4,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":4,
         "sum_visit_length":794,
         "bounce_count":0,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      }
   ],
   "2017-12-21":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":1,
         "nb_actions":14,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":14,
         "sum_visit_length":287,
         "bounce_count":0,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      }
   ],
   "2017-12-22":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":2,
         "nb_actions":9,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":7,
         "sum_visit_length":219,
         "bounce_count":0,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      }
   ],
   "2017-12-23":[  

   ],
   "2017-12-24":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":1,
         "nb_actions":12,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":12,
         "sum_visit_length":480,
         "bounce_count":0,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      }
   ],
   "2017-12-25":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":3,
         "nb_actions":4,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":2,
         "sum_visit_length":7,
         "bounce_count":2,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      }
   ],
   "2017-12-26":[  

   ],
   "2017-12-27":[  
      {  
         "label":"Mobile Safari",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":9,
         "nb_visits":9,
         "nb_actions":9,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":1,
         "sum_visit_length":0,
         "bounce_count":9,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/MF.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==MF"
      },
      {  
         "label":"Android Browser",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":4,
         "nb_visits":4,
         "nb_actions":4,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":1,
         "sum_visit_length":0,
         "bounce_count":4,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/AN.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==AN"
      },
      {  
         "label":"Internet Explorer",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":4,
         "nb_visits":4,
         "nb_actions":4,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":1,
         "sum_visit_length":0,
         "bounce_count":4,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/IE.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==IE"
      },
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":3,
         "nb_visits":3,
         "nb_actions":3,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":1,
         "sum_visit_length":0,
         "bounce_count":3,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      },
      {  
         "label":"Chrome Mobile",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":2,
         "nb_visits":2,
         "nb_actions":2,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":1,
         "sum_visit_length":0,
         "bounce_count":2,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CM.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CM"
      },
      {  
         "label":"Firefox",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":2,
         "nb_visits":2,
         "nb_actions":2,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":1,
         "sum_visit_length":0,
         "bounce_count":2,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/FF.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==FF"
      },
      {  
         "label":"Opera",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":1,
         "nb_actions":1,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":1,
         "sum_visit_length":0,
         "bounce_count":1,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/OP.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==OP"
      },
      {  
         "label":"Safari",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":1,
         "nb_actions":1,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":1,
         "sum_visit_length":0,
         "bounce_count":1,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/SF.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==SF"
      }
   ],
   "2017-12-28":[  

   ],
   "2017-12-29":[  

   ],
   "2017-12-30":[  

   ],
   "2017-12-31":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":1,
         "nb_actions":6,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":6,
         "sum_visit_length":41,
         "bounce_count":0,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      }
   ],
   "2018-01-01":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":2,
         "nb_actions":9,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":7,
         "sum_visit_length":103,
         "bounce_count":0,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      }
   ],
   "2018-01-02":[  

   ],
   "2018-01-03":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":3,
         "nb_actions":6,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":3,
         "sum_visit_length":250,
         "bounce_count":1,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      }
   ],
   "2018-01-04":[  

   ],
   "2018-01-05":[  

   ]
}
```

How can I define only the filename, for example in the above **JSON** the `logo` filename for Chrome Browsers is `CH.png`?

I would like to get the `object` but return only the filename for use in my JS as

```
logo.src = 'https://example.com/img/browser-icons/' + logoName + '.png';
```

Alternatively, the same could be done with the `object` `segment`, returning for example `CH` from `browserCode==CH`.

My full code is displaying the JSON data as a table

```js
$.getJSON('https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/index.php?module=API&method=DevicesDetection.getBrowsers&idSite=2&period=day&date=2017-12-17,2018-01-05&format=json&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff', (browser_data) => {
  Array.prototype.groupBy = function(key) {
    var path = key.split('.');
    var result = {};
    try {
      this.forEach(function(item) {
        // es6: path.reduce((a, b) => a[b], item)
        type = path.reduce(function(a, b) {
          return a[b]
        }, item) || 'null';
        if (!result[type])
          result[type] = [];
        result[type].push(item);
      });
      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return {};
    }
  };

  function getPropertySum(key, arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => (key in b ? a + b[key] : a), 0)
  }
  // one array of all dates
  let browserCode = ('segment');
  let flattenArr = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(browser_data));
  // object of grouped dates by device
  let groups = flattenArr.groupBy('label');
  let table = document.getElementById('browserTable');
  table.innerHTML = '';
  Object.keys(groups).forEach(function(label) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    let logw = document.createElement('td');
    let logo = document.createElement('img');
    let lab = document.createElement('td');
    let nbv = document.createElement('td');
    let nbu = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(logw);
    row.appendChild(lab);
    row.appendChild(nbv);
    row.appendChild(nbu);
    logw.appendChild(logo);
    logo.src = 'https://discovrbookings.com/wp-content/themes/discovr-application/assets/img/browser-icons/' + logoName + '.png';
    lab.innerHTML = label;
    nbv.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_visits', groups[label]);
    nbu.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_uniq_visitors', groups[label]);
    table.appendChild(row);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="browserTable"></table>
```

Comment: You can use array.filter method to get only logo part of object key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the logo string get the last part with the file name assigned to the variable `logoName`. I have added a snippet towards the bottom of your code.

```js
$.getJSON('https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/index.php?module=API&method=DevicesDetection.getBrowsers&idSite=2&period=day&date=2017-12-17,2018-01-05&format=json&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff', (browser_data) => {
  Array.prototype.groupBy = function(key) {
    var path = key.split('.');
    var result = {};
    try {
      this.forEach(function(item) {
        // es6: path.reduce((a, b) => a[b], item)
        type = path.reduce(function(a, b) {
          return a[b]
        }, item) || 'null';
        if (!result[type])
          result[type] = [];
        result[type].push(item);
      });
      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return {};
    }
  };

  function getPropertySum(key, arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => (key in b ? a + b[key] : a), 0)
  }
  // one array of all dates
  let browserCode = ('segment');
  let flattenArr = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(browser_data));
  // object of grouped dates by device
  let groups = flattenArr.groupBy('label');
  let table = document.getElementById('browserTable');
  table.innerHTML = '';
  Object.keys(groups).forEach(function(label) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    let logw = document.createElement('td');
    let logo = document.createElement('img');
    let lab = document.createElement('td');
    let nbv = document.createElement('td');
    let nbu = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(logw);
    row.appendChild(lab);
    row.appendChild(nbv);
    row.appendChild(nbu);
    logw.appendChild(logo);

    // Get the logo property and use split on the string
    logoProperty = getPropertySum('logo',groups[label]);
    var logoPropSplit = logoProperty.split("/");
    var logoName  = logoPropSplit [logoPropSplit.length-1];
    // End of edit

    logo.src = 'https://discovrbookings.com/wp-content/themes/discovr-application/assets/img/browser-icons/' + logoName + '.png';
    lab.innerHTML = label;
    nbv.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_visits', groups[label]);
    nbu.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_uniq_visitors', groups[label]);
    table.appendChild(row);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="browserTable"></table>
```

Comment: Perfect, just had to remove `'png'` from the `logo.src`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the file name you can `.split()` the `logo` property value by `"/"`, `.pop()` the array

```
let url = "plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png";

let logoName = url.split("/").pop();
```

Comment: This looks like the best solution, yet I cannot get this to work on the `logo` `object` in my JSON file to return the image name for multiple types of browser. Could you copy my snippet from above to use in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Object.keys` to iterate through your large JSON object?

```
var data = {  
   "2017-12-17":[  

   ],
   "2017-12-18":[  
      {  
         "label":"Chrome",
         "nb_uniq_visitors":1,
         "nb_visits":1,
         "nb_actions":5,
         "nb_users":0,
         "max_actions":5,
         "sum_visit_length":184,
         "bounce_count":0,
         "nb_visits_converted":0,
         "logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/browsers\/CH.png",
         "segment":"browserCode==CH"
      }
   ]
}
var keys = Object.keys(data); // this will output ['2017-12-17','2017-12-18',..]



 keys.forEach(function(d){ 
    data[d].forEach(function(i){
        console.log(i.logo);
    });
});
```

## Output

> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/CH.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/MF.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/CH.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/MF.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/AN.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/IE.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/CH.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/CM.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/FF.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/OP.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/SF.png
>
> plugins/Morpheus/icons/dist/browsers/CH.png